# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' when password print on bash

Tags: mysql, mysql-connect

I am using mysql 5.6
I want to connect mysql from bash.

> mysql -u root -pAdmin@1234

i am getting following error-

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

But if i used -

> mysql -u root -p

and provide password manually then it works.
Can any one help me out this issue.

Comment: [please refer this link to how to create user with **localhost** or **ip** based user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw) And grant all privileges to that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your password is not exactly "Admin@123". If there are any special characters, use the escape character " \ " in the command line and try it.

Comment: thanks for help.
due to special characters in the password field, mysql is not allowed on bash.
once i changed the password without special character i got login through bash.